# Realm delete listener

Tags: android, realm

I'm trying to listen Realm's notification when I delete some items from database. So I tried this code:

```
    realm.where(Book.class).findAllAsync().addChangeListener(new RealmChangeListener<RealmResults<Book>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChange(RealmResults<Book> element) {
            // nothing changed here
            Log.d(TAG, "onChange: size = "+element.size());
        }
    });

    realm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
        @Override
        public void execute(Realm realm) {
            Book book = realm.where(Book.class).equalTo("id", 45).findFirst();
            book.deleteFromRealm();
        }
    });
```

But the listener never triggered. I need to decide which items were deleted by user, so that I can remove them from `RecyclerView`. Do you have any idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that there's no any delete listener specified for Realm. But, Realm notification will be triggered when you delete the items from database. We can take an advantage here by re-check which list items are no longer available in Realm database, and delete them from list (`RecyclerView` or `ListView`). Here's the example:

```
    @Override
    public void onChange(RealmResults<Article> articles){
        Set<Integer> ids = new HashSet<>(articles.size()), toRemove = new HashSet<>();
        List<ModelArticle> models = new ArrayList<>(articles.size());
        for (Article article : articles){
            ModelArticle model = adapter.getValueById(article.id);
            if (model == null) {
                // insert new data into list
                model = new ModelArticle(article);
                models.add(model);
            }else{
                // if data already exists, just update it
                model.updateArticle(article);
                adapter.notifyItemChanged(adapter.getPositionById(model.id));
            }
            ids.add(model.id);
        }
        // find which items should be removed from list
        for (ModelArticle model : adapter.getValues())
            if (!ids.contains(model.id))
                toRemove.add(model.id);

        // remove all items that are no longer available
        adapter.removeAllById(toRemove);
        // add all items that just added into database
        adapter.addAll(models);
    }
```

By the way, I use Realm 2.2.1

Answer (score 0):

You need to retain the results as a field reference

```
private RealmResults<Book> books;

public void someMethod() {
    books = realm.where(Book.class).findAllAsync();
    books.addChangeListener(new RealmChangeListener<RealmResults<Book>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChange(RealmResults<Book> element) {
            // nothing changed here
            Log.d(TAG, "onChange: size = "+element.size());
        }
    });

    realm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
        @Override
        public void execute(Realm realm) {
            Book book = realm.where(Book.class).equalTo("id", 45).findFirst();
            book.deleteFromRealm();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: But, I also need to listen the changes in different activity. Using this technique only affects the current activity. I need to decide which items were deleted by user, so that I can remove them from `RecyclerView`. Does realm support delete notification?

Comment: But you can have only 1 activity in the front at a time, no? You can just do the same thing (field reference and query) in the other activity as well.